# UV output mapping

Tags: uv, .fbx

I am a noob.  My app developer wants me to send him my scans with UVs mapped out.  I have only basic UV knowledge.  I can unwrap, add a texture and save the files okay.  But he wants me to export FBX files with separate .map files I think.  I cannot understand his output instructions.  I do not know where these "output" settings are in Blender.

here is the menu that I cant locate:[image: and the instructions][image]

Comment: That menu is from substance painter (different app), Blender does not have that kind of menu, in order for you to export the different maps, you need to bake your textures one by one

Answer (score 0):

Those are not UV maps, those are texture images (although you will need to have a UV mapped model in order to generate them.)  From what you've shown, they're not .map files, they're .png files, which you can save from Blender's image editor.

It looks like a metalness workflow, which in Blender terms, is the Principled BSDF.  Albedo is your base color.  Metallic is obviously metallic, smoothness is roughness (probably inverted, but you should check with whoever is doing your shaders to see how the mapping compares, and maybe get some smoothness sample images to make sure Blender's roughness models are matching.)  Normal is your tangent space normal map.  AO is not used for Blender in Cycles (it can be used for the Specular BSDF in Eevee though), and is probably generated by a high-to-low-poly bake of ambient occlusion.

Metallic and smoothness are on the same image.  Presumably, the alpha channel is used for smoothness, while the RGB channels are all the same metalness value, but you should check with whoever is doing your shaders.